# checking for duplicates in row only of a 2d array in java

Tags: java

I want to check if a duplicate exists in only the row of a 2D array and replace it.

So, if the array is:

```
7,  5,  6,   1,  7,  5,   7,  1    // would change the 7 in [4] and [6]
2,  4,  3,  -1,  7,  5,   8,  3    // would change the 3 in [7]
8,  7,  2,  -3,  7,  1,   5,  1  
5,  7,  3,   2,  4,  5,  -4,  8  
6,  1,  8,   2,  2,  6,   1,  3

int row = 0;
if (row < zipcodelist.length) {
    for (int z = 0; z < zipcodelist[row].length; z++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < zipcodelist[row].length; y++) {
            if (zipcodelist[row][z] == zipcodelist[row][y]) {
                zipcodelist[row][y] = 1 + generator2.nextInt(8);
            } else if (zipcodelist[row][z] != zipcodelist[row][y]) {
                System.out.println("Not duplicate");
            }
        }
    }
    row++;
}
```

But with this code, everything changes, not just the duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the generator2.nextInt is to generate a random number, the code to do that is: 
Random generator2 = new Random();

Comment: i am not getting what do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with the next element in the row in second iteration not the 2nd element in the list

so

```
 for(int y = 1; y<zipcodelist[row].length; y++){
```

should be replaced by

```
 for(int y = z + 1; y<zipcodelist[row].length; y++){
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use a HashSet. Your current nested loops are O(n^2).

```
int [] array = {7,5,6,1,7,5,7,1};

Set alreadyExamined = new HashSet();

for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(alreadyExamined.contains(array[i])){
        array[i] = new Random().nextInt(8)+1;
    }
    else{
        alreadyExamined.add(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Note: If your objective is to remove duplicates, then it's possible that the newly generated number is another duplicate of a previous number.

Answer (score 0):

But here if you remove duplicate in first iteration like follow,

7,  5,  6,   1,  **7**,  5,   7,  1

7,  5,  6,   1,  **6**,  5,   **5**,  1

then next iteration can made duplicate again like follow,

7,  **5**,  6,   1,  6,  5,   5,  1

7,  **5**,  6,   1,  6,  **8**,   **7**,  1

so as I think this type of random number genarators not suitable for this.

Comment: What would be a better alternative?